# partition by returns duplicate rows

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, window-functions

Let's say I have a weather table:

```
MONTH, DAY, LOW
6, 1, 67.47084426063374
6, 2, 66.90195288599919
6, 3, 62.16084275276963
```

I want to select the avg low temperature for the month and am trying this:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
    select p.month, avg(p.low) over (partition by p.month) avg_low
    from table p
) t;
```

The averaging is working but I'm getting 3 duplicate records back. How can I just return a single record?

(Also, when I try to round these `round(avg(p.low),2)`, I'm told "FROM keyword not found where expected")

Comment: You have placed a comma after avg_low please remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want aggregation:

```
select p.month, avg(p.low) as avg_low
from table p
group by p.month
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MONTH,ROUND(AVG(LOW),2) avg_low FROM  table  GROUP BY MONTH
```

That's it :)